# Minimum value in 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, printing

I have 2 arrays, first array holds all the values for resource_wastage and 2nd array holds all the value for power_consumed. To implement a fuzzy logic I need to check of both resource wastage and power consumption are low at the same time then my output would be the array index, if one of them is low and second is not then I should move on to the next value in the array.

Eg:

```
for(int i=0, i<n; i++) 
if(res_was[0] is low in all res_was[i=0 to n] && [pow_con[0] is low in all pow_con[i=0 to n])
    {
      print i;
      break;
    }

    else continue with next value in arrays;
```

Please help how to I implement this, I mean check if the values in both arrays are low simultaneously.

Comment: What means low? Due you have a reference value for both under which it must be or do you mean the minimum value within each array?

Comment: What should be returned if nothing is found matching the criterias?

Comment: Check this scenario: if res_was[0] is low and pow_con[2] then what will be result to print i;... kindly edit & make it clear your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this. Arrays have special method for Min search.

```
var resMin = res_was.Min();
var powMin = pow_con.Min();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
{
      if(res_was[i] == resMin && pow_con[i] == powMin)
      {
         Console.writeLine(i);
         break;
      }    
}
```

May be you will need use more complex Min method. You can read about all of them in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this;

find the minvalue and minvalue position then compare if equal proceed your process...

```
        int _ires_wasminValue = Enumerable.Range(0, res_was.Length).Min(i => res_was[i]);
        int _imin_res_was_pos = Array.IndexOf(res_was, _ires_wasminValue);

        int _ipow_cons_minValue = Enumerable.Range(0, res_was.Length).Min(i => res_was[i]);
        int _imin_pow_cons_pos = Array.IndexOf(res_was, _ires_wasminValue);

        if (_imin_pow_cons_pos==_imin_res_was_pos)
        {
            Console.writeLine(_imin_pow_cons_pos);                
        }
```